# Why is this simple Javascript code not running on my website?

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie JSer here. I'm trying to get a new phrase to appear every time a website page is loaded. However, when I reload the page, the phrase does not appear.

```js
var phrases = [
  'Phrase one',
  'Phrase two',
  'Phrase three'
]

function newPhrase() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (phrases.length));
  document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrases[num];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>StickComs: Free Comics for Everyone</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Google font: Roboto -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body onload="newPhrase()">
  <!-- Phrase Banner -->
  <div class="container-fluid" id="phrase-banner">
    <p id="phrase">
      <!-- Phrases display here -->
    </p>
    <script src="generator.js"></script>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your console log reporting any errors?

Comment: I suggest first learning some debugging, then come back here when you have a specific issue. At the very least we need an error message as @Adam says.

Comment: Your code looks ok so it's hard to know, Try clicking the `<>` button in your post and making a runnable example on here. Put console.logs in your js file to make sure it's being loaded, finding the element etc.

Comment: No, Adam, it is not.

Comment: Works great for me.

Comment: I just created your html file and generator.js files in the same (sandbox) directory and it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't want to edit the OP's answer so here is the code in a runnable format. It seems to work here so I would venture that the `generator.js` file might not be loaded.

First check the network requests in the developer tools and see if it it successfully loaded.

Second if it is loaded, then since you are using the `onload` event for the body, the script might have loaded but not been parsed and executed before the event attempts to execute the function (although I believe that should cause an error to be reported).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>StickComs: Free Comics for Everyone</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap: jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Google font: Roboto -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body onload="newPhrase()">
  <!-- Phrase Banner -->
  <div class="container-fluid" id="phrase-banner">
    <p id="phrase">
      <!-- Phrases display here -->
    </p>
    <script>
      var phrases = [
        'Phrase one',
        'Phrase two',
        'Phrase three'
      ]

      function newPhrase() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (phrases.length));
        document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrases[num];
      }
    </script>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to run JavaScript in your simple html page modify generator.js to be like below:

```
 let phrases = [
     'Phrase one',
     'Phrase two',
     'Phrase three'
 ]

 function newPhrase() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (phrases.length));
    document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrases[num];
 }
window.onload = newPhrase;
```

and remove

```
onload="newPhrase()"
```

in the body tag as it actually will not work at all.